# How to use HTML elements yandex qa tools selenium wrapper without page factory (@FindBy using) but in dynamic pages

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, htmlelements

HTML elements yandex qa tools selenium wrapper works well and init elements when elements are on page object inited with `@FindBy` annotation and `HtmlElementLoader.populatePageObject(this, ((WebDriverBrowser)Browser.getDriver()).getWebDriver());` in Page Object constructor

But if page content changes dynamically I want to create HtmlElement on the way without @FindBy lake for example:

```
public static void openNavigator(String navigatorName) {
    String navigatorPath = String.format(MENU_OBJ_XPATH_PATTERN, navigatorItemMenuName);
    Element navigatorMenu = new Element(By.xpath(navigatorXpath));
    navigatorMenu.waitForVisible();
}
```

In this case Element constructor looks like

```
public Element(By locator) {        
    this.locator = locator;
}
```

Got error: `no such element: Unable to locate element`

And even if I directly try to init element

```
HtmlElementLoader.createHtmlElement(Element.class, Browser.getBrowser().getWebDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//td[contains(text(),'Navigator')]")))
```

Got error

```
no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//td[contains(@id,'cnt-start')]//*[contains(text(),'Navigator')]"}
  (Session info: chrome=68.0.3440.106)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578737 (49da6702b16031c40d63e5618de03a32ff6c197e),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
```

Is it possible to use Html elements wrapper like this?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, timeoutInSeconds);
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(navigatorXpath)));
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough context to offer a best solution, but here is one: define your items as an array of elements. Then you could iterate through to find a specific one:

```
@FindBy(xpath = "./menu_locator")
public class SiteMenu extends HtmlElement {
    @FindBy(xpath = "./generic_item_locator")
    List<HtmlElement> items

    public clickOn(String navigatorName) {
        for (HtmlElement item: items) {
            if (item.getText() == "navigatorName") {
                item.click();
            }
        }
        throw new ElementNotFoundException("Navigator item not found")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the point is how to init HtmlElement not with @FindBy annotation in case dynamic page loading. But with lazy initialization for example using HtmlElement constructor with By argument

Comment: There is no way to do it dynamically with HtmlElements. It's been done by purpose - to avoid bringing unnecessary complexity into your tests. I've never seen a case where tests would benefit from using dynamic locators. So, what's your case?

Comment: I see. My case is CMS which has main fuctionality as pages creation with different page elements. For example, I create page with the list of some elements. And I have many cases where elements can be differed while page composing so that I get different result page-blocks. And if I use HtmlElements I should create a big amount of different blocks, which is not appropriate solution

Comment: Or for example how can I process page block inside the page if the block is dynamic (it can appear and dissapear in case of the condition)?

Comment: You could just define that block and then check it's visibility in your test before processing it.